# Navbar-Toggle Without Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

 .navigation {
     height: 75px;
     width: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     margin-top: -20px;
     background-color: #4169E1;
}

 .brand {
     position: absolute;
     padding-left: 5px;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 6px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 1.4em;
}
 .brand a, .brand a:visited {
     color: #FFF;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .nav-container {
     max-width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

 nav {
     float: right;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 0.938em;
     /*font-size: 15px;*/
     font-weight: bold;
}

 nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

 nav ul li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}

 nav ul li a,nav ul li a:visited {
     display: block;
     padding: 0 20px;
     line-height: 75px;
     color: #C0C0C0;
     background: #4169E1;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 nav ul li a{
     background: #4169E1;
     color: #C0C0C0;
}

 nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:visited:hover {
     background: #4169E1;
     color: #FFF;
}

 .navbar-dropdown li a{
     background: #4169E1;
     color: #C0C0C0;
}

 nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after, nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
     padding-left: 4px;
     content: ' \025BE';
}

 nav ul li ul li {
     min-width: 190px;
}

 nav ul li ul li a {
     padding: 15px;
     line-height: 20px;
}

 .navbar-dropdown {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     z-index: 1;
     text-align: center;
     box-shadow: 0 0 35px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

/* Mobile Navigation */
 .nav-mobile {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: transparent;
     height: 75px;
     width: 70px;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
     .nav-mobile {
         display: block;
    }
    
     nav {
         width: 100%;
         padding: 75px 0 15px;
    }
    
     nav ul {
         display: none;
    }
    
     nav ul li {
         float: none;
    }
    
     nav ul li a {
         padding: 15px;
         line-height: 20px;
         background: #FFF;
         color: #4169E1;
         font-family: Arial;
         font-size: 20px;
         text-align: left;
         font-weight: bold;
    }
    
     nav ul li ul li a {
         /*padding-left: 30px;*/
    }
    
     .navbar-dropdown {
         position: static;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
     .nav-list {
         display: block !important;
}
}

 #navbar-toggle {
     position: absolute;
     left: 18px;
     top: 22px;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

 #navbar-toggle span, #navbar-toggle span:before, #navbar-toggle span:after {
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 3px;
     height: 5px;
     width: 30px;
     background: #FFF;
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     content: '';
     transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

 #navbar-toggle span:before {
     top: -10px;
}

 #navbar-toggle span:after {
     bottom: -10px;
}
 #navbar-toggle.active span {
     background-color: transparent;
}

 #navbar-toggle.active span:before, #navbar-toggle.active span:after {
     top: 0;
}

 #navbar-toggle.active span:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 #navbar-toggle.active span:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

I have a Non B S one page smooth scrolling template that I tested on lots of screen sizes, and it loads / views great on All of the sizes that I tested!  However, All of the J S scripts that I've tested in the area of auto closing the menu in mobile mode when clicking on links appear to be of No help.  How can I get the mobile menu to auto close on click Without using B S?  Much Thanks for a / the Solution!  :--)

```js
    //Scroll Smoothly
  
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("a.scroll-smoothly").click(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              
              $("html, body").animate({
                  scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
                }, 500);
            });
            
        });
  
  
  (function($) { 
  $(function() { 
      

    //  Open and Close Nav 
    $('#navbar-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });


    // Hamburger Toggle
    $('#navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });


    // If a Link Has A DropDown, Add Sub Menu Toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.navbar-dropdown').slideToggle("slow");

      // Close DropDown When Selecting Another DropDown
      $('.navbar-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide("slow");
      e.stopPropagation();
    });


    // Clicking Outside the DropDown Removes the DropDown Class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.navbar-dropdown').hide();
    });
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- The Above 3 Meta Tags MUST Come First In The Head; Any Other Head Content MUST Come AFTER These Tags -->
    
    <title>SITE TITLE</title>
    
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="ssb-img/favicon.ico"/>


    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link href="css-js/ssb-main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Navbar CSS -->
    <link href="css-js/ssb-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
     
  </head>
  
  <body>

<div class="navigation nav-collapse">
    
<div class="nav-container">
    
    <div class="brand">
      <a class="scroll-smoothly" href="#header"><img src="top-logo.svg" height="65" alt="Top Logo" title="Top Logo"></a>
    </div>
    
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="navbar-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
          
        <li>
          <a class="scroll-smoothly" href="#header">TOP</a>
        </li>
        
        <li>
          <a href="#!">ABOUT / WHY</a>
          
          <ul class="navbar-dropdown">
              
            <li>
              <a  class="scroll-smoothly" href="#about">ABOUT / WHY</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">BRIEF TERMS</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">BRIEF PRIVACY STANDARDS</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">CLOSE (X)</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li>
          <a href="#!">TICKETS / DEMO</a>
          
          <ul class="navbar-dropdown">
              
            <li>
              <a class="scroll-smoothly" href="tickets">GET TICKETS</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#demo">SSL SECURE DEMO</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">CLOSE (X)</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
               
        <li>
          <a href="#!">FEEDBACK</a>
        </li>
        
      <li>
          <a href="#!">CONTACT</a>
          
          <ul class="navbar-dropdown">
              
            <li>
              <a href="#info">CONTACT INFO</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#form">CONTACT FORM</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#software">GET OUR SOFTWARE</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">CLOSE (X)</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        </ul>
      
    </nav>
  </div>
  
</div>

<section id="header" style="height: 100vh; background: #C0C0C0">
    
<h2 style="line-height: 75px; color: #C0C0C0">HIDDEN GAP</h2>

<h2>HEADER!</h2>    
    
</section>

<section id="about" style="height: 100vh; background: #FFF; padding-top: 75px">
    
<h2>ABOUT!</h2>
    
</section>  
    
    <!-- jQuery Library -->
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    
    <script src="css-js/j-q-3.3.1-j-q.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Main JS -->
    <script src="ssb-css-js/ssb-main.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Navbar JS -->
    <script src="ssb-css-js/ssb-navbar.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Auto Close Mobile Menu -->
    
    <script>Looking for the Proper Mobile Menu Auto Close J S WITHOUT Using B S!</script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#navbar-toggle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      $('nav .nav-list').slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    
    // If a Link Has A DropDown, Add Sub Menu Toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.navbar-dropdown').slideToggle("slow");

      // Close DropDown When Selecting Another DropDown
      $('.navbar-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide("slow");
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
     $('html').click(function() {
      $('.navbar-dropdown').hide();
    });
    
 })
```

```css
    body{
    margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

 .navigation {
     height: 75px;
     width: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     margin-top: -20px;
     background-color: #4169E1;
}

 .brand {
     position: absolute;
     padding-left: 5px;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 6px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 1.4em;
}
 .brand a, .brand a:visited {
     color: #FFF;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .nav-container {
     max-width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

 nav {
     float: right;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 0.938em;
     /*font-size: 15px;*/
     font-weight: bold;
}

 nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

 nav ul li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}

 nav ul li a,nav ul li a:visited {
     display: block;
     padding: 0 20px;
     line-height: 75px;
     color: #C0C0C0;
     background: #4169E1;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 nav ul li a{
     background: #4169E1;
     color: #C0C0C0;
}

 nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:visited:hover {
     background: #4169E1;
     color: #FFF;
}

 .navbar-dropdown li a{
     background: #4169E1;
     color: #C0C0C0;
}

 nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after, nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
     padding-left: 4px;
     content: ' \025BE';
}

 nav ul li ul li {
     min-width: 190px;
}

 nav ul li ul li a {
     padding: 15px;
     line-height: 20px;
}

 .navbar-dropdown {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     z-index: 1;
     text-align: center;
     box-shadow: 0 0 35px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

/* Mobile Navigation */
 .nav-mobile {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: transparent;
     height: 75px;
     width: 70px;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
     .nav-mobile {
         display: block;
    }
    
     nav {
         width: 100%;
         padding: 75px 0 15px;
    }
    
     nav ul {
         display: none;
    }
    
     nav ul li {
         float: none;
    }
    
     nav ul li a {
         padding: 15px;
         line-height: 20px;
         background: #FFF;
         color: #4169E1;
         font-family: Arial;
         font-size: 20px;
         text-align: left;
         font-weight: bold;
    }
    
     nav ul li ul li a {
         /*padding-left: 30px;*/
    }
    
     .navbar-dropdown {
         position: static;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
     .nav-list {
         display: block !important;
}
}

 #navbar-toggle {
     position: absolute;
     left: 18px;
     top: 22px;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

 #navbar-toggle span, #navbar-toggle span:before, #navbar-toggle span:after {
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 3px;
     height: 5px;
     width: 30px;
     background: #FFF;
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     content: '';
     transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

 #navbar-toggle span:before {
     top: -10px;
}

 #navbar-toggle span:after {
     bottom: -10px;
}
 #navbar-toggle.active span {
     background-color: transparent;
}

 #navbar-toggle.active span:before, #navbar-toggle.active span:after {
     top: 0;
}

 #navbar-toggle.active span:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 #navbar-toggle.active span:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation nav-collapse">
    
<div class="nav-container">
    
    <div class="brand">
      <a class="scroll-smoothly" href="#header"><img src="top-logo.svg" height="65" alt="Top Logo" title="Top Logo"></a>
    </div>
    
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="navbar-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
          
        <li>
          <a class="scroll-smoothly" href="#header">TOP</a>
        </li>
        
        <li>
          <a href="#!">ABOUT / WHY</a>
          
          <ul class="navbar-dropdown">
              
            <li>
              <a  class="scroll-smoothly" href="#about">ABOUT / WHY</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">BRIEF TERMS</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">BRIEF PRIVACY STANDARDS</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">CLOSE (X)</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li>
          <a href="#!">TICKETS / DEMO</a>
          
          <ul class="navbar-dropdown">
              
            <li>
              <a class="scroll-smoothly" href="tickets">GET TICKETS</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#demo">SSL SECURE DEMO</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">CLOSE (X)</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
               
        <li>
          <a href="#!">FEEDBACK</a>
        </li>
        
      <li>
          <a href="#!">CONTACT</a>
          
          <ul class="navbar-dropdown">
              
            <li>
              <a href="#info">CONTACT INFO</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#form">CONTACT FORM</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#software">GET OUR SOFTWARE</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#">CLOSE (X)</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        </ul>
      
    </nav>
  </div>
  
</div>

<section id="header" style="height: 100vh; background: #C0C0C0">
    
<h2 style="line-height: 75px; color: #C0C0C0">HIDDEN GAP</h2>

<h2>HEADER!</h2>    
    
</section>

<section id="about" style="height: 100vh; background: #FFF; padding-top: 75px">
    
<h2>ABOUT!</h2>
    
</section>  

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For time sake, I Only added the Extra J S, and that makes the DropDown Close on Desktop, and Mobile, Without being able to scroll.  I plan to take a day or so Off from this.  :--)

Comment: H T: I'll look over your script more today or tomorrow.  As far as I currently know, the Added J S Auto Closes mobile menus Without smooth scrolling down the page.  I need into Auto Close as the page scrolls to the linked to section.   

Comment: H T:  I used the JS that you suggested, with Removing the other JS that I had, and the mobile nav menu appears to become frozen.  When I use it With the other JS, then it closes the mobile menu Without scrolling.  :--)

Comment: Thanks H T!  Does anybody else here have a possible solution for this?  I'm on Hault until I can get this.   :--)

Comment: I Added the below JS, and now mobile menus Close after sliding to the various sections.  However, when clicking on Non navbar links, the mobile menu now Opens.  Yikes!  LOL

Comment: <!-- Auto Close Mobile Menu ONLY For THIS TEMPLATE --> <script> $('.mobile-menu-hide').on('click', function () { $('nav ul').slideToggle(); $('#navbar-toggle').removeClass('active'); }); </script>

Comment: It looks like position: fixed; is causing the Newest issue. :--)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
nav ul {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You should add responsive css so you can scroll mobile menu also in mobile device.

Comment: I Added what you suggested, and that Didn't change anything.  So, I Tested Removing (display: none;), and that keeps the mobile menu Always Open.  Looks like you're close!  :--)

Comment: The mobile menu is Great otherwise!  :--)